# ufw firewall DROP icmp from ALL to a specific IP address on my server

Tags: firewall, iptables

My server has apache2 on a single interface with multiple IPs on sub-interfaces. I want to reject an icmp echo request from all external IPs to a specific IP assigned to one of my sub interfaces but allow the icmp to the other IPs on the same interface:

1. eth2 - 10.128.20.252
2. eth2:1 - 10.128.20.11
3. eth2:2 - 10.128.20.12
4. eth2:3 - 10.128.20.13 <-want to block icmp to only this IP
5. eth2:4 - 10.128.20.14

Answer (score 2):

Edit the /etc/ufw/before.rules file and change the Ip to suit your needs. Then do:
     # ufw reload

## put this before the icmp ok codes section, it works

## drop icmp to specific IP

-A ufw-before-input -p icmp --icmp-type echo-request -d 10.128.20.13 -j REJECT